# Java tomcat sound

Tags: java, tomcat, audio

i got the folloing warning

> 28-Jun-2016 16:09:36.482 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [PickByVoice] appears to have started a thread
>   named [Java Sound Event Dispatcher] but has failed to stop it. This is
>   very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502) 
>   com.sun.media.sound.EventDispatcher.dispatchEvents(EventDispatcher.java:182)
>   com.sun.media.sound.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:222) 
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I got a webservice and when a request is called the webservice will playback a sound file. It doesnt work.

It works in eclipse useing the tomcat server. dont know why

hope someone can help me

thx

Comment: can you specify, or provide some detail as to what libraries you are using for this sound to function? also, where does it not work? on a different tomcat server? What tomcat server version is eclipse installed with as compared to your local version?

Comment: I am jusing tomcat apache-tomcat-7.0.70 and the libaries for sound are the javax.sound.sample.*. tried it arleady on tomcat 9 but doesnt work aswell.

Comment: to make sure I understood you, so it works on tomcat 7 built into eclipse, but nothing else, correct?

Comment: can you provide some of your code so we can see why such an error would be thrown?

Comment: i will do it tomorrow ok?

Answer (score 0):

here is some code:

class Webservice

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

//Import all the needed classfiles 
import org.PickByVoice.bluetooth.btautoconnect;
import org.PickByVoice.model.Languages;
import org.PickByVoice.model.WavFile;
import org.PickByVoice.service.AudioService;
import org.PickByVoice.service.UploadService;
import org.PickByVoice.exception.Statues;




@Path("restwebservice")                     //rootpath of the Servlet 
@Singleton                                  //Singleton is used to creat only one instance for all requests. So the Wav-Filelist needs to initiate only once.
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) 
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class RaspberryPiResources  {

    //creating instance, setting variables
    long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Languages listLanguages=new Languages();
    AudioService audioService = new AudioService();
    btautoconnect bluetoothAutoConnection=new btautoconnect();
    public static WavFile wavFileList;
    final String 
    String currentId="",currentShelfId="",currentstate="nothing scanned",language,location,currentthread;
    int i=0;

    public RaspberryPiResources(){
        language="eng";
        audioService.seterrorList("eng");   // Language specific error files are loaded
    }

    @GET
    @Path("init")
    public Response initialization(@DefaultValue("eng") @QueryParam ("language") String language,@QueryParam("warehouse") String country) throws InterruptedException, IOException{ 
        audioService.playinit(1L,language);         
        return Response.status(Statues.INITSUCESS).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).entity("ok").build();             //Status code 600
    }

@GET
    @Path("/sounds/messages/{messageId}")
    public Response outputErrorSounds(@PathParam("messageId") final long soundId) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        currentthread=Thread.currentThread().getName();

        audioService.setcurrentThread(currentthread);
audioService.errorSound(soundId,language,currentstate,currentId,currentthread);                                             //Playing the error message and repeating the scann-Id
        return Response.status(Statues.OK).entity(Statues.OK.getReasonPhrase()).build();                                            //Status code 603
    }
```

class AudioService

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;




public class AudioService{

    public AudioInputStream audioInStream = null;
    public FilterIds filterId=new FilterIds();
    public File file;
    public SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
    char firstcharacter;
    String compare="",currentThread="",Threadcompare="",vrrr="";
    WavFile wav;

    public AudioService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //Stops and closes the SourceDataLine
    public void closeAudioLine(){
        sourceDataLine.stop();
        sourceDataLine.flush();
        sourceDataLine.close(); 
    }

    public void playinit(Long idOfSound, String language) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        wav=new WavFile(language);
        String soundpath=wav.getErrorSoundFileList().get(idOfSound);
        currentThread="init";
        playAudio(soundpath);
    }


public synchronized String errorSound(Long soundId, String language,String currentState,String currentId, String Threadname) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        currentThread="playerrorSound";
        if(!currentThread.equals("playerrorSound")){
            ack();
        }
        if(Threadname.equals(Thread.currentThread().getName()))
        {
        Threadcompare=Thread.currentThread().getName();
        String soundpath=wav.getErrorSoundFileList().get(soundId);                      
        playAudio(soundpath);                                                           
        try{    
            audioInStream.close();  
            }catch(IOException ioe)
            {ioe.printStackTrace();}

        }
        return "end";
        }
```

Comment: sourceDataLine.open(format); this is the one who creates the error

Comment: fixed it. used a DAC shield for the raspberry pi. dont know why but by using the normal sound output of the raspberry pi solved the problem thx for the help anyway